# Properly update Telegram

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, telegram

I have Telegram Desktop, and every now and then the *Update Telegram* button appears at the bottom of the Telegram app GUI.

If I run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` nothing happens. There aren't any telegram packages in the list of packages.

If I click on the update bottom from the GUI, nothing happens and after a while the button pops up again.

How can I solve this? Can I update from a terminal?

Comment: How did you install the app? I recommend getting the package from the [official website](https://desktop.telegram.org/) and extract it anywhere you like. You'll be able to do in-app update.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install telegram-desktop
```

---

You don't have the Telegram snap package from the Ubuntu Software application installed. If you want to install the latest stable version of Telegram, the name of the snap package to install is telegram-desktop and the commands to install it are:

```
sudo apt install snapd  
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

Telegram is a popular messaging protocol with encryption and security as its key focus. telegram-sergiusens is the latest version of Telegram, the same version as the Telegram file that is available at the official Telegram website. The command to update telegram-desktop is:

```
sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop
```

Answer (score 12):

I have Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.
At first, I installed Telegram Desktop by typing

```
sudo apt-get install telegram-desktop
```

in the command-line but it installed a very old version and I couldn't update it.
Then I deleted it (`sudo apt remove telegram-desktop`) and installed it via snap again:

```
sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

This command managed to install the latest version and it even makes it possible to update it via:

```
sudo snap refresh telegram-desktop
```

NOTE: if you don't have snap on your system, just install it before installing Telegram Desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

Answer (score 2):

After you installed telegram using `sudo apt install telegram-desktop` command, you can easily update it by:

1. First go to the official [telegram-desktop website](https://desktop.telegram.org/)
2. And then download the zip file
3. Extract the zip file
4. Go to the extracted folder
5. If opened, close telegram before proceeding to the next step
6. Click on the update file, finito!

[screenshot of extracted update file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b78LU.png)