# Telegram Persian font changed after upgrade to 18.10!

Tags: fonts, telegram

My telegram font changed after upgrading to 18.10! Does anyone know why this happened?

[image: screenshot]

When i open telegram in command line these errors appear:

```
Fontconfig warning: line 5: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: line 6: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: line 6: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: line 6: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: line 7: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: line 7: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: line 9: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 34: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 35: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf", line 36: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf", line 8: unknown element "description"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 4: unknown element "its:rules"
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: unknown element "its:translateRule"
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'translate'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 5: invalid attribute 'selector'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'xmlns:its'
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf", line 6: invalid attribute 'version'
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
```

---

**Answer:**

I solved the problem by changing `~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/fc-custom-1.conf` contents to:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <dir>/usr/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir>/usr/local/share/fonts</dir>


    <dir>/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts</dir>
    <dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>mono</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>monospace</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
            <string>sans</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
            <string>sans-serif</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <cachedir>/var/cache/fontconfig_11</cachedir>
    <cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig_11</cachedir>
    <cachedir>~/.fontconfig_11</cachedir>
    <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
        <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="embeddedbitmap">
        <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
        <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
        <const>hintslight</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
        <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
    <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
        <const>rgb</const>
    </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

and creating a directory named `fonts` next to the `fc-custom-1.conf` file and pasting a font named `B_Nazanin_YasDL.com.ttf` into this directory.

Comment: What version of Telegram are using? Check this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/954165/properly-update-telegram

Comment: @JoKeR Telegram 1.4.2

Comment: You should try to downgrade your fonts library. Im trying the same. If I succeed I will let you know.

Comment: Or you should wait for telegram to provide a new version with font support

Comment: just install telegram from Ubuntu archive [Source](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/issues/5172)

Comment: For now Just update to latest version.

Answer (score 17):

I encountered the exact same problem after upgrading Kubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 !

Trying to figure out what is this weird font, I browsed and found out that Telegram is using **KacstArt** font (probably because this is the first font in the list when it fetches all system fonts).

I solved my problem by limiting telegram font search-paths into a single isolated folder that contains only my desired font. The procedure goes like this:

1. There is a font configuration file `~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/fc-custom-1.conf` open it up.
2. Comment out all `<dir>` and `<cachedir>` entries there (simply wrap them between `<!--` and `-->`).
3. Add a `<dir>[your desired folder]</dir>` just after `<fontconfig>` at the beginning of the file with `[your desired folder]` being the path pointing to a custom folder containing only your desired font.
   (e.g. I created a folder in `~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/myfonts` then added `tahoma.ttf` and `tahomab.ttf` there)
4. Restart telegram and enjoy.

Comment: Putting your desired font in ~/.fonts and commenting out every dir but that might be a slightly faster fix.

Answer (score 11):

Here is how I fixed this issue for Persian:

- Close Telegram
- Create directory: `~/.fonts`
- Add a font with its **different weights** [I used [Vazir](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font)]
- Create file: `~/.fonts.conf` and add these lines to it:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match target="pattern">
        <test name="family" qual="any">
            <string>sans serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit mode="assign" binding="same" name="family">
            <string>Vazir</string>
        </edit>
    </match>
    <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

- Clear font caches:

`fc-cache -f -v`

`rm -r ~/.cache/fontconfig_11`

- Now open Telegram :)

Comment: For portable telegram application in debian-XFCE system just only copy [Vazir](https://github.com/rastikerdar/vazir-font/releases/download/v21.0.1/vazir-font-v21.0.1.zip) fonts pack into the `.local/share/fonts/` and restart telegram solve the issue.

Comment: Complete answer in Persian language on Iranian UBUNTU Community [link](https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=149887.msg1167009#msg1167009)

Answer (score 8):

Just remove it and install from Ubuntu archive.

```
sudo apt install snapd

sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update**:
Since telegram 1.8.4 there is no `fc-custom-1.conf` file, so here is another solution (assuming that the telegram binary is in `/opt/Telegram/Telegram`):

1. Create a config file for telegram font (path is optional):

   ```
   touch /opt/Telegram/fonts.conf
   ```

   and add these lines to it:

   ```xml
   <?xml version='1.0'?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
   <fontconfig>

    <match>
     <edit mode="prepend" name="family">
      <string>Vazir</string>
     </edit>
    </match>

    <dir>~/.local/share/fonts</dir>
    <dir>/usr/share/fonts/</dir>

   </fontconfig>
   ```

   I used **Vazir** font, if you want to use another font(e.g. **Tahoma**) you must change the `<string>Vazir</string>` to `<string>Tahoma</string>`.
2. Modify the telegram `.desktop` file, which is located at `~/.local/share/applications/telegramdesktop.desktop`, to:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Version=1.0
   Name=Telegram Desktop
   Comment=Official desktop application for the Telegram messaging service
   TryExec=/opt/Telegram/Telegram
   Exec=env FONTCONFIG_FILE=/opt/Telegram/fonts.conf /opt/Telegram/Telegram -- %u
   Icon=telegram
   Terminal=false
   StartupWMClass=TelegramDesktop
   Type=Application
   Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;Qt;
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/tg;
   Keywords=tg;chat;im;messaging;messenger;sms;tdesktop;
   X-GNOME-UsesNotifications=true
   X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
   ```
3. Place your font in `~/.local/share/fonts`.

Comment: Thank you! it works perfect.

Comment: Only this answer worked on Telegram 2.0.1

Comment: this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Just simply remove this file by typing this command in your terminal :

```
killall Telegram && rm -rf ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/fc-custom-1.conf
```

Comment: Didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

Close Telegram app

Copy your font to a directory (for example `cp Tahome.ttf /home/alice/Telegram`)

```
vim ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop/tdata/fc-custom-1.conf
```

remove all `<dir> </dir>`

add one `<dir>path_to_your_font_dir</dir>`

then
change all font name to your font name.

My config like:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
        <dir>/home/alice/Telegram</dir>
        <dir prefix="xdg">fonts</dir>
        <match target="pattern">
                <test qual="any" name="family">
                        <string>Tahoma</string>
                </test>
                <edit name="family" mode="assign" binding="same">
                        <string>Tahoma</string>
                </edit>
        </match>
        <cachedir>/var/cache/fontconfig_11</cachedir>
        <cachedir prefix="xdg">fontconfig_11</cachedir>
        <cachedir>~/.fontconfig_11</cachedir>
        <match target="font">
        <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
                <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit mode="assign" name="embeddedbitmap">
                <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
                <bool>true</bool>
        </edit>
        <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
                <const>hintslight</const>
        </edit>
        <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
                <const>lcddefault</const>
        </edit>
        <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
                <const>rgb</const>
        </edit>
        </match>
</fontconfig>
```

then

```
fc-cache -f -v
rm -r ~/.cache/fontconfig_11
```

Open Telegram app :-)

Answer (score 0):

What Nima said will work, but the best way is to install the snap or the flatpak version of telegram.

first purge your current installation:

```
sudo apt purge telegram-desktop
```

then delete the following folder:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/TelegramDesktop
```

then you can simply do the following :

```
sudo apt install snapd && sudo snap install telegram-desktop
```

Comment: not good idea ! try solving problems not covering up

Answer (score 0):

just install a Persian font like [Shabnam](https://github.com/rastikerdar/shabnam-font) or any other Persian fonts you like and restart your system.