# Telegram's problem with persian font

Tags: fonts, gtk, apparmor, telegram

I've installed Telegram on my Ubuntu 18.04. My system is updated and everything is updated. 
When I try to open telegram, for Persian texts, it uses a very weird monospace like font. I've tried writing the following to the `~/.fonts.conf` file but it doesn't take effect.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
        <match target="pattern">
                <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                        <string>az</string>
                </test>
                <test name="family">
                        <string>sans-serif</string>
                </test>
                <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="same">
                        <string>Noto Naskh Arabic</string>
                </edit>
        </match>

        <match target="pattern">
                <test name="lang" compare="contains">
                        <string>az</string>
                </test>
                <test name="family">
                        <string>serif</string>
                </test>
                <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="same">
                        <string>Noto Naskh Arabic</string>
                </edit>
        </match>
</fontconfig>
```

When I run telegram from the terminal I get the following log:

```
Gtk-Message: 21:37:50.085: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 21:37:50.101: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.201\" (uid=1000 pid=13326 comm=\"telegram-desktop \" label=\"snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties\" member=\"GetAll\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=1093 comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
nmReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type=\"method_call\", sender=\":1.201\" (uid=1000 pid=13326 comm=\"telegram-desktop \" label=\"snap.telegram-desktop.telegram-desktop (enforce)\") interface=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" member=\"GetDevices\" error name=\"(unset)\" requested_reply=\"0\" destination=\"org.freedesktop.NetworkManager\" (uid=0 pid=1093 comm=\"/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon \" label=\"unconfined\")"
"Object path cannot be empty"
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem, I've checked the other topics over the net and they mostly consist of changing the fonts configuration file, but I think there might be sth wrong with `apparmore.`

Comment: I think you should [report this issue](https://snapcraft.io/telegram-cli) to the developer of the telegram-cli snap.

Comment: You should see this page. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41062/forcing-font-size-based-on-language-in-fonts-conf.
My problem has been solved with this.

Answer (score 1):

There is similar topic in [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1087439/telegram-persian-font-changed-after-upgrade-to-18-10#comment2085746_1087439) about telegram and its bad support for Persian language fonts.

A good news is that Telegram on newer release add default support to Persian with adding [Vazir](https://rastikerdar.github.io/vazir-font/) font family.

For you I suggest to remove `telegram-desktop` package if install with Ubuntu repository and download the latest one from [official website](https://desktop.telegram.org/) to use latest update of telegram.

`apt purge telegram-desktop`

If you prefer more info on installing telegram in this method please read my answer on [Iranian UBUNTU Community](https://forum.ubuntu.ir/index.php?topic=149887.msg1167009#msg1167009).